# Very high speed counter (2GHZ)

Tags: digital-logic, timer, counter, wave

I'm trying to build a high speed counter to measure the time delay between two radio waves . I'm thinking of using a MC100EP016A counter which works at a maximum frequency of 1.4 GHz but I cannot find out a clock IC as an input to this counter .

It requires an input high voltage of 2075 mV to 2420 mV and an input low voltage of 1355 mV to 1675 mV . this input range is much above the LVPECL output range most voltage controlled crystal oscillators provide and I cannot find a LVPECL to PECL converter at 1.4 ghz.

What can I do?

or are there any alternatives?

please help ...